# If I update a react module such that existing code functions but Jest snapshot tests may break, should that be a major version bump?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, semantic-versioning

Let's suppose I maintain a module for a react component, and am working on a PR to add a new feature.

As part of that feature work, let's also suppose I've refactored the component to remove some internals that were previously visible if you'd captured a Jest snapshot of the rendered component. (Suppose I've removed an internal intermediate component and not anything that affects the DOM output of the component). Functionally, the component is identical and all existing code is compatible.

Should I release my feature as a new *major* version of the component because some users' snapshot tests might need to be updated? Or is a *minor* version bump sufficient?

Comment: I don't fully grok what; _"refactored the component to  remove some internals that were previously visible if you'd captured a Jest snapshot of the rendered component"_, actually equates to in terms of changes to the Public API, or if that's a feature your pkg provided.  What you've got to ask yourself when determining whether to bump the _Major_ version is defined in [#8](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8), It essentially boils down to: **1.** Does this change that I've made introduce any backwards incompatible changes to the public API? **2** If yes, then bump the Major, otherwise don't.

Comment: You need to provide more information for anyone to answer this question definitely.  You provided conflicting information.  You say all existing code is compatible, and then you worry that your customers tests might fail.  Which is it?  Please [edit] your post.  Is capturing a Jest snapshot within the scope of your API?  Post the relevant before and after interface code.  If you have previous releases that included publicly accessible interfaces, that are no longer available, then it is a breaking change.

Comment: BTW, you should break your work into two submissions.  First submit the cleanup/refactor work, then submit the new feature.

Comment: This is kind of a weird case to describe, but this change was an API improvement. I rewrote the internals to support a more ergonomic API, and then re-implemented the old, less-friendly API using the new API and marked it deprecated. This approach makes it easer to remove, and makes the preferred API also the cleanest codepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

As [RobC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626157/if-i-update-a-react-module-such-that-existing-code-functions-but-jest-snapshot-t?noredirect=1#comment107314084_60626157), it boils down to whether the *public* API has changed or broken. After some thought, I'm persuaded that a Jest snapshot of an Enzyme render that includes internals not visible in the final rendered DOM is more like leakage of a *private* API, and therefore not intended to be protected by a major semver bump.

I published my change as a minor version. Will comment on this answer if users complain.